# Obtaining element types

Tags: jquery, html, dom, tree, find

Suppose I have a hypothetical html layout such as this (while hypothetical, I'm implementing something similar, but have streamlined it for the sake of the question):

```
<div id='start' class='checkpoint'>
  <ul>
    <li><input name='need_this'/></li>
    <li><input name='need_also'/></li>
    <li>
      <div id='stop' class='checkpoint'>
        <ul>
          <li><input name='ignore_this' /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <li>
      <div>
         <div><input name='need_again' /></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input name='need_aswell' />
</div>
```

What I would like to do, beginning with $('#start'), is to obtain all elements with the 'name' attribute, unless they exist inside a new checkpoint class. While I am familiar with .find() and .nextUntil(), my understanding is that as these read through the html progressively, and would stop stop as soon as they hit the 'checkpoint' class midway through? I would like to search around and beyond any '.checkpoint' element,s until the close of the #start div.

Would be grateful if someone could point me towards the right approach for this? (it's possibly some jQuery condition I'm unfamiliar with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#start [name]').not('#start .checkpoint [name]')
```

though I don't know how efficient this is...

---

Side note: `input` elements should be inside `<form>`s.

Comment: Hi Felix - thanks, works great. Might I also ask, for versatility, how would this be written when in a plugin context using 'this' instead of having the id of the element in the string? (in particular, I'm unsure on how to rewrite the not() clause to accomodate 'this')

Comment: @girlafraid: I guess it would be something like `this.find('[name]').not(this.find('.checkpoint [name]'))`

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I could think of with your HTML code:

```
$('#start').find('input[name]').each(function()
{    
    if(!$(this).parents('div[id!=start]').hasClass('checkpoint'))
    {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

Demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NarutoDevil/vhz9E/).